# How can I extract a pdf page with PDFMiner based on a string I am trying to locate?

Tags: python, pypdf, pdfminer

I am trying to extract a specific page using PDFminer and Python 2.7.

I am currently able to extract a page based off a page number but I am unable to extract a page based off a specific string that I am trying to look for in the pdf document. I was able to do this with PyPDF2 but the extraction from the page was not as clean as with PDFminer so I decided to use that instead. The text comes out much nicer with PDFminer.

Here is my code from PDFminer currently:
    '''

```
base_path = "/Users/username/Documents"

my_file = os.path.join(base_path + "/" + "Personal-Auto-Policy.pdf")
log_file = os.path.join(base_path + "/" + "Output3.txt")

password = ""
extracted_text = ""

fp = open(my_file, "rb")
parser = PDFParser(fp)

document = PDFDocument(parser, password)

if not document.is_extractable:
    raise PDFTextExtractionNotAllowed

rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
laparams = LAParams()

device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)

interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr,device)

target = ""

NumPages = PDFPage.get_pages(fp)


for pageNumber, page in enumerate(NumPages):
    for line in str(page):
        if("296 S 468211" in line):
            interpreter.process_page(page)

            layout = device.get_result()

            for lt_obj in layout:
                if isinstance(lt_obj, LTTextBox) or isinstance(lt_obj, LTTextLine):
                    extract_text = lt_obj.get_text()

fp.close()

with open(log_file, "wb") as my_log:
    my_log.write(extracted_text.encode('utf-8'))
print("Target page extraction success!")
```

'''

When I run this I don't get the output expected but if I do something similar with PyPDF2 it grabs the correct page. As I previously stated, PyPDF2's text extraction is not the best so I would prefer to use PDFminer.